# Make two dependent vectors point in a certain direction when chained in 2D

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, angle

Ok, I got two vectors $A$ and $B$, and $E=A+B$. I got a vector $T$ pointing in my target direction. I want $E$ to point in the same direction as $T$.
Now the tricky part is that the angle of $A$ is $\alpha$ and the angle of $B$ is $\frac 5 3 \alpha$. Also, $|A| \ne |B|$.

Below is an illustration including an equation I got so far, however I'm not able to solve that equation.
Known values: $|A|, |B|, T$.

[image: Illustration]

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to vary to get what you ask? Are you looking for $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for alpha.

Comment: So $\|A\|$ and $\|B\|$ are known and fixed.

Comment: Yes. Basically the question is how much the vectors need to be rotated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to solve this numerically. The equation that needs to be solved is

$$ \tan ( \epsilon - \alpha ) = \frac{B \sin \left( \frac{2}{3} \alpha \right)}{A+B \cos \left( \frac{2}{3} \alpha \right) } $$

The simplest method would be single point iteration. Starting from $\alpha_0=0$ do

$$ \alpha_i = \epsilon - \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{B \sin \left( \frac{2}{3} \alpha _{i-1}\right)}{A+B \cos \left( \frac{2}{3} \alpha_{i-1} \right) } \right)$$

It should converge within 7 to 12 iterations to enough accuracy.

---

Example:

$A=5$, $B=2$, $\epsilon = 60°$

1. $\alpha_0 = 0$
2. $\alpha_1 = 1.04719755119659 {\rm rad}$
3. $\alpha_2 = 0.852871937781031$

$\vdots$

4. $\alpha_{12} = 0.882200775986220 {\rm rad} = 50.5463811471765°$

### Appendix

Lay a coordinate system along *A* and measure along to get
$$E \cos(\epsilon-\alpha) = A + B \cos(\frac{2}{3}\alpha) $$

Take the perpendicular direction and measure
$$ E \sin(\epsilon-\alpha) = B \sin(\frac{2}{3} \alpha) $$

Divide the two to get the solution.

Comment: This really worked, thanks alot. Can you explain how you came up with the solution maybe?

Comment: See appendix now.